# what is est way to use, combine Keycloak in airflow

Tags: airflow, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am new in the field, I would like to know how can I use keycloak with apache airflow,
I saw some tutorial that talks about it but are not detailed,
I would like your help to help me understand how can I work with keycloak and apache airflow
What I tried and studied

https://awslife.medium.com/airflow-authentication-with-rbac-and-keycloak-2c34d2012059

https://aksharau.substack.com/p/configuring-airflow-with-keycloak

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14002